# Mount using offline file system (OFS+FUSE)

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount, fuse, mount-point

I am trying to explore OFS (Offline file system) built on the top of FUSE and still exploring it.

http://offlinefs.sourceforge.net/wiki/

I installed it on both Fedora and Ubuntu 14.04,however whenever I try to mount any local directory using mount utility, I get the “Transport endpoint not connected” for mount directory.

This is how I am running it :

```
mount –t ofs file:/home/user/Downloads/src /home/user/Downloads/mountdir
```

The above executes without error and if I run mount command on ../mountdir ,it correctly says

```
ofs on /mountdir type fuse.ofs.
```

However when I try to browse /mountdir I get “Transport endpoint not connected”.I even tried unmounting and restarting the machine,no use!

Can someone point me to a right direction.

Comment: did you notice the second `/` in the `file:` uri in the initial example? it may be important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using it incorrectly, you must have two forward slashes in the URI that is specified as the mount device i.e. `file://`.

As an e.g.

```
$ sudo mount -t ofs file://usr /tmp/mnt
$ ls /tmp/mnt
bin/  etc/  games/  include/  lib/  lib32/  libx32/  local/  sbin/  share/  src/
$ sudo umount /tmp/mnt
```

with a single `file:/` we have:

```
$ sudo mount -t ofs file:/usr /tmp/mnt
$ ls /tmp/mnt
ls: cannot access /tmp/mnt: Transport endpoint is not connected
$ sudo umount /tmp/mnt
```

Now if you're intending to use a remote filesystem with `OFS`, which is the primary use-case, you have to first install the relevant remote filesystem packages on the OS you're using, then use, for example, if we've got `cifs`, which is the newer name for `smb`/`samba`:

```
sudo mount -t ofs cifs://127.0.0.1/Music /tmp/music
```

Now, if you need to pass options to `cifs`, such as the password/username/a config file, you can use the `remoteoptions` parameter, so for example for guest account access:

```
sudo mount -t ofs -o remoteoptions=guest cifs://127.0.0.1/Music /tmp/music
```

or, if you're using a credentials file (see [mount.cifs](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mount.cifs) manual page), you can use:

```
sudo mount -t ofs -o remoteoptions=credentials=/etc/remotecreds.conf cifs://127.0.0.1/Music /tmp/music
```

for remote options, you use a `:` as the separator (it gets swapped for a `,` when passed into the underlying mount command), so to mount as an explicit user/password:

```
sudo mount -t ofs -o remoteoptions=username=mike:password=mike1 cifs://127.0.0.1/Music /tmp/music
```

Comment: :Thanks.It worked for local directory.Now i am trying to mount a remote samba share using OFS mount utility.The samba share is working properly and is accessible via smbclient.However when i try to execute `sudo mount -t ofs smb://192.168.11.129/sharedfolder /home/usr/Downloads/test/` ,I get an error **unknown filesystem type 'smb'**.What can be the reason behind this.OFS supports smb as per their documentation.

Comment: depending on your linux distro and it's age, you can end up with it called either `cifs` or `smb`. On my debian system, it's called `cifs` so you use `cifs://` for the uri, rather than `smb://`.

Comment: I am trying to mount it on ubuntu machine.Both smb:// and smbfs:// do not work.

Comment: Does not work for cifs://. Error:wrong fs type, bad option. Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Sounds like you don't have `mount.cifs` on your system. Have you tried adding the `cifs-utils` package? e.g. by trying `apt-get install samba cifs-utils`?

Comment: I have mount.ofs in my system. ofs is built on the top of FUSE.I want to mount using OFS mount utility and they say it supports samba.  [link]http://offlinefs.sourceforge.net/wiki/usage/getting_started

Comment: Your **OS** has to support the filesystem that OFS is using - it's simply a layer on top of the underlying filesystem. If you don't have samba/cifs support installed on your system, then you can't use OFS on top of it. What OFS does is mount the remote filesystem somewhere else and arbitrate access to it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70865/discussion-between-willmcavoy-and-petesh).

Answer (score 0):

It only worked in my case (ubuntu 16) with the following command:

> `mount -t ofs -o remoteoptions=username=XXXXX:password=xxxx:guest:vers=3.0 cifs://HOST/dir /mountpoint`